# Toyota corolla security engine lock

Tags: engine, toyota, corolla, key, security

I just bought a Toyota Corolla 2013 Special Edition last week. Yesterday, suddenly once I entered the key and I was to start the engine, it started honking with the security key flashing. The engine was starting that time. After 2 tries, honking again, but the engine was making a continuous noise when starting. Then after two more tries, now the engine doesn't even start. I don't hear a start sound.

It looks like the key fob is broken and the car was thinking i'm a robber and it locked the engine. What should I do now? Is the battery also dead now?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your car is equipped with aftermarket alarm system. They don't last too long. Until the security light goes away, the car most likely won't start. If there is an aftermarket alarm system on it, it should be removed or replaced.

Comment: It doesn't start after that. So maybe the battery is dead now? Does the battery die after 5,6 starts?!

Comment: Turn the switch on (second position) and all of the lights should turn on inside the dash. If the battery is low, the starter should atleast make a clicking sound. If the battery is completly drained, there will be no lights in the dash and no starter clicking sounds.

Comment: Interesting. No issues with the light. But when I did a jump start, it turned on. Now the engine (check engine?) indicator turns on. Probably there are some problems with the car.